# I can't use imagecopyresized

Tags: php, image, gd

I have a problem with the [GD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library) functions. When I upload an image on localhost, everything works fine, and a thumbnail is created, but when I upload my website on hosting then `imagecopyresized` just fails. When I insert in a blank page, that function (whole resize function), it works just fine.

What could be the problem?

Actually, when the upload function try to upload the file then the GD functions don't work.

Comment: Define "fails". Can you look into the source code of the generated image and see whether there are any PHP error messages in it?

Comment: no there i arent any error messages in the image

Comment: Are you sure GD is installed on your hosting server?

Comment: yes i am sure, i checked with phpinfo

Comment: When I insert in a blank page, that function (whole resize function) it works just fine on HOSTING.

Comment: Can you show the code that fails?

Answer (score -2):

If your scripts work fine on a blank (free and not bound) page, then the problem surely goes to the CMS you are using. It may redirect to htaccess file you are using or even some specifications of your website.